# Keras backend - ImportError: cannot import name ctc_ops

Tags: keras

I have installed keras but when I write import keras I am getting the error :  **ImportError: cannot import name ctc_ops**, I want to change the backend from tensor flow to theano but  cannot find "keras.json" as mentioned here : https://keras.io/backend/ . Please help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the [official documentation](https://keras.io/backend/), you cannot have this json file using `~/.keras/keras.json` unless you have already run it at least once before. I suggest you to create on with the default configuration:

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain where to put the json file in this post? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310035/how-to-change-keras-backend

Answer (score 0):

If you have run Keras at least once, you will find the Keras configuration file at:

$HOME/.keras/keras.json

If it isn't there, you can create it.

NOTE for Windows Users: Please change $HOME with %USERPROFILE%.

Answer (score 0):

Get a more recent version of tensorflow. The default tensorflow installed by conda is currently 0.9.0, which too old. Try upgrading for instance with `conda upgrade -c conda-forge tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`if you don't use conda.