# How to change Keras backend (where's the json file)?

Tags: python, command-line, theano, keras

I have installed Keras, and wanted to switch the backend to Theano. I checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036748/keras-backend-importerror-cannot-import-name-ctc-ops), but still have no idea where to put the created json file. Also, below is the error I got when running `import keras` in Python Shell:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import keras   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       from . import backend   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 64, in
>   
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow

When running `python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"` from Windows command line, I got:

> Using TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in    File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       from . import backend   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 64, in
>   
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I am using mac, could you let me know how to change the keras's backend from tensorflow to theano

Comment: To find `keras.json` in Windows, a shortcut is **`%USERPROFILE%/.keras`**, referenece: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/15615/83048

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After looking at keras sources ([this place](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/25dbe8097fba9a6a429e19d0625d78c3b8731527/keras/backend/__init__.py#L18)):

Start up your python-binary and do the following

```
import os
print(os.path.expanduser('~'))
# >>> C:\\Users\\Sascha'  # will look different for different OS
```

- This should be the base-directory
- Keras will build an folder `.keras` there where `keras.json` resides (if it was already created). If it's not there, create it there
- Example: `C:\\Users\\Sascha\\.keras\\keras.json'`

Comment: @GeorgeLiu Please go ahead to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: a shortcut is **`%USERPROFILE%/.keras`**  by https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/15615/83048

Answer (score 10):

In case of Ubuntu,the following worked for me:

The '.keras' folder is present in your home directory,but is hidden.So,you need to unhide the hidden files in your home directory.
You can see the hidden files in Ubuntu by

- View-> show hidden files or
- pressing ctrl+H.

You can now see the '.keras' folder in your home directory.Inside that folder,you will see the 'keras.json' file which you can modify to switch the keras backend to *theano* according to the official documentation https://keras.io/backend/

Comment: the OP is using windows so the dot files and folders are not hidden by default. Moreover, ctrl+H or view->show hidden files are ubuntu specific commands

Comment: solved my issue even though OP asked for windows. I think it is not that bad to answer such question in a way you know. So it can help people anyway.

Answer (score 7):

"**Can’t find your keras.json file? : Windows**
 On most systems the keras.json  file (and associated sub-directories) will not be created until you open up a Python shell and directly import the keras  package itself.

If you find that the ~/.keras/keras.json  file does not exist on your system, simply open up a shell, (optionally) access your Python virtual environment (if you are using virtual environments), and then import Keras:

```
$ workon keras_tf
$ python
>>> import keras
>>> quit()
```

"

Referenced from : [keras-with-tensorflow/theano-backend](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/14/installing-keras-with-tensorflow-backend/)

Answer (score 6):

For those with a python shell open:

```
import os

with open(os.path.expanduser('~')+'\\.keras\\keras.json','w') as f:
    new_settings = """{\r\n
    "epsilon": 1e-07,\r\n
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",\n
    "backend": "theano",\r\n
    "floatx": "float32"\r\n
    }"""
    f.write(new_settings)

import keras
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use,

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='theano'
```

or

```
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to change the config, the json is available here: `~/.keras/keras.json`

To do this dynamically in python 2.7 you can run:

```
from keras import backend as K
import os

def set_keras_backend(backend):

    if K.backend() != backend:
        os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = backend
        reload(K)
        assert K.backend() == backend

set_keras_backend("theano")
```

Answer (score 2):

For Linux systems, the hidden .keras directory will be created in the user’s home directory. To observe whether or not it has been created, run the following command from your home directory (the -a allows you to see hidden files and directories).

```
    ls –a
```

If the directory is there, then cd into it and modify the keras.json file. If it’s not there, then create the directory with

```
    mkdir .keras
```

Then create the file with

```
    touch keras.json
```

Then edit the file to make the config changes you referenced to change the backend engine to Theano.

This process is covered fully in [this video](https://youtu.be/sRF_-bwxru4).

Comment: Instead of using just
ls -a
use
ls -a | grep keras
to check if .keras directory is present or not.
It will just be more easier.

Answer (score 1):

The official Keras Documentation may help you. This [link](https://keras.io/backend/) shows how to change the backend of Keras. You have to change the ~/.keras/keras.json from 'backend': 'tensorflow', to 'backend': 'theano'.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add this informative post. I'm using anaconda for my task. And imported keras through my anaconda python. So keras got installed in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

There are 2 folders in site-packages: `keras` & `Keras-1.0.8.dist-info`.

In `Keras-1.0.8.dist-info`, there's a file called `metadata.json`. This by default has "Theano" as backend. So, if you change that to tensorflow, you will get tensoflow backend.

Hope it will help someone who has might type of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Solution:

Google's TensorFlow is default backend for keras but for example if u want to change it with theano then
First check if the alternate backend  you wish to work with is installed successfully by importing it in python shell:

> > import theano as th

if that works fine

Step 2: if you have installed keras, theano in virtualenv then go to virtualenv directory

e.g virtualenv/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/

open **init**.py
change line 27

```
Default backend: TensorFlow.
_BACKEND = 'theano'
```

and thats it

open python shell
and import keras

> > import keras as kd

Answer (score 0):

Type following and press enter on command prompt:

```
%USERPROFILE%/.keras/keras.json
```

Change backend in the opened text file and save it.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you can use this command to open keras.json file in vi editor and editing and saveing

```
sudo vi $HOME/.keras/keras.json
```

or use the following for opening in gedit

```
sudo gedit $HOME/.keras/keras.json
```