# Keras-ImportError: cannot import name ctc_ops

Tags: keras

I have Anaconda 4.3.1 installed in my laptop after the commands `cd /home/username/anaconda3`and `source bin/activate ~/anaconda3` my package starts .
And I installed keras using pip3 `conda install keras` inside my anaconda. package.and made a document named **keras.json** inside my **keras** folder.
When I start my Python in anaconda3 and import `keras` this happens

```
>>> import keras'
Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tushar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "/home/tushar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/activations.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import backend as K
  File "/home/tushar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/tushar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import ctc_ops as ctc
ImportError: cannot import name 'ctc_ops'
```

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036748/keras-backend-importerror-cannot-import-name-ctc-ops) I could not get any solution. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey @Leva7 can you help me out on this.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same exact issue (I was using pip instead of conda to install keras / tensorflow, however). Make sure you have the most up-to-date version of tensorflow (`tensorflow-1.0.1` as of March 31st, 2017).

```
sudo pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

fixed the problem for me (I was running `tensorflow-0.9.0rc0` before and was getting the same `ImportError: cannot import name ctc_ops` error as you)